# Connecting jQuery scripts with test results

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I've been trying to find a way to render the Submit button on a dynamic quiz useless until a user has selected an answer to every question. I could simply insert "required" before the answer's closing tags, but I have three different types of answers - including questions that require users to choose any number of checkboxes.

The solution appears to be a jQuery script that requires a selection for each question. But I can't get anything to work. I think maybe I'm just not getting my scripts properly associated with my form.

This is an example of my test code:

```
<div class="Answer">
  <label class="Wide" for="q'.$QID.'-'.$Value.'"><div class="Radio"><input type="radio" name="q'.$QID.'[]" id="q'.$QID.'-'.$Value.'" value="'.$Value.'" style="display: none;"> '.$Value.'. '.$QA.'</div></label></div>
```

This is what the HTML looks like:

```
<li id="q7">
  <div class="Question">Media that pretend to be opposed to the mainstream media are called...</div>
  <div class="Answer">
    <label class="Wide" for="q7-A"><div class="Radio"><input type="radio" name="q7[]" id="q7-A" value="A" style="display: none;"> A. alternative media</div></label></div>
  <div class="Answer">
    <label class="Wide" for="q7-B"><div class="Radio"><input type="radio" name="q7[]" id="q7-B" value="B" style="display: none;"> B. soapboxes</div></label></div>
  <div class="Answer">
    <label class="Wide" for="q7-C"><div class="Radio"><input type="radio" name="q7[]" id="q7-C" value="C" style="display: none;"> C. underground media</div></label></div>
  <div class="Answer">
    <label class="Wide" for="q7-D"><div class="Radio"><input type="radio" name="q7[]" id="q7-D" value="D" style="display: none;"> D. yellow journalism</div></label></div>
</li>
```

And this is the form that processes everything:

```
<div id="quiz2" rel="key" style="margin-top: 50px;">
  <form action="grade.php" method="post" id="quiz">
    <ol>
      <li style="display: none;">
<?php
echo join ($Base, '');
?>
    </li>
    </ol>

    <input type="hidden" name="PreviousURL" value="<?php echo $MyURL; ?>" id="url" />
    <input type="hidden" name="user_token" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['user_token']) ? $_POST['user_token'] : '' ; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Quiz" />
  </form>
</div><!-- quiz-container -->
```

So what do I have to do to make the following jQuery work with the above? I changed the ID number to quiz, matching my form. I don't understand what "index" means, but I've tried replacing "value" with a number of variables. Nothing works.

```
<script>
var inputs = $('#quiz :input');

inputs.each(function(index, value) {
  if ($(value).val() == '') { //check if the input is empty 
    //return the error
    echo 'ERROR!';
  }
});
</script>
```

Here's another script that looks interesting, but I don't know how to associate it with my form:

```
<script>
function checkInput() {
  var inputs = $("input");
  check = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.size(); i++) {
    var iVal = $(inputs[i]).val();

    if (iVal !== '' && iVal !== null) {
     $(inputs[i]).removeClass('input-error');
   } else {
  $(inputs[i]).addClass('input-error');
  $(inputs[i]).focus(function() {
    $("input").removeClass('input-error');
    $(inputs[i]).off('focus');
    });
  check++;
   }
  }

if (check > 0) {
  return false;
 } else {
 return true;
 }
}

checkInput()
</script>
```

I've been playing with both scripts, manipulating various variables, but every time I click the Submit button without answering a question, it forwards me to the next page.

Comment: echo 'ERROR!'; ?? does that work?

Comment: I can't echo anything, because as soon as I press the submit button, I'm forwarded to the next page.

Comment: i mean is there a command called "echo" in Javascript?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I guess I'm not really sure; I'm not that familiar with Javascript.